# can't open vscode editor on linux after ssh-remote from windows

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio-code

I've been using vscode locally on a linux machine successfully.
Last night, I installed ssh-remote and connected to this linux machine from a windows machine.  Everything appeared to be working fine from windows.

I just sat down at the linux machine this morning and could not open any of the files shown in the left pane (double clicking did nothing).  I tried right clicking and selecting "open to the side".  This caused a blank screen to open to the side.

Thinking maybe this was due to my windows laptop still being open at home, etc, I closed vscode on the linux machine and navigated to a random text file in my home directory using Nautilus (ubuntu file manager), right-clicked open in vscode, and it started vscode with no open files, no open folders, etc.

Finally, I restarted my linux machine, logged in, and tried the most direct, reproducible test I could think of, which still just started vscode with a blank screen (no editor):

```
(base) me@pc:~$ ls -l .bashrc && code .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 4279 May  6 13:09 .bashrc

<then vscode GUI opens, displaying no editors>
```

Comment: What happens when you start vscode on Linux and then choose File->Open and navigate to one of the files to edit? Does the file then open correctly in vscode on the Linux machine? When you say "displaying no editors", do you mean vscode opens and displays things like the menu, the side-bar the terminal, etc.. but no edit window is shown?

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin:
"What happens when you start vscode on Linux and then choose File->Open and navigate to one of the files to edit? Does the file then open correctly in vscode on the Linux machine? " no.  
"When you say "displaying no editors", do you mean vscode opens and displays things like the menu, the side-bar the terminal, etc.. but no edit window is shown? "
yes

Answer (score 0):

The following "worked" as in now I can open and edit stuff, but all my extensions have to be reinstalled:

```
sudo dpkg --purge code 
rm -fr ~/.config/Code
rm -fr ~/.vscode
sudo apt install ~/Downloads/code_1.57.0-1623259737_amd64.deb
```

Note, last night when accessing from windows, I enabled settings-sync.  No idea if that screwed things up, but in the past I've used mac laptops to connect this way (the Microsoft ssh-remote extension with settings sync turned on at both ends) and never had a single problem.

Comment: I would stay away from sync -- as far away as possible when one is on Linux and one on Windows. You may run into version issues, like with the latest 1.5.7 new workspace trust, if your windows box auto-updates but your Linux box doesn't. Glad you got it working. Now if vscode just had more sane keyboard shortcuts, it would be a nice little Linux editor.